# Sharding database through nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sharding

I am very much new to the concept of node js. My officers assigned me task to find sharding of database through nodejs. I google and found an npm package, called cluster-pool. How to test it?

```
var app = express();

var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(    

    connection(mysql,{

        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password : 'tiger',
        port : 3306, 
        database:'mydb'

    },'pool') 

);
```

To connect single database I could use this. How to integrate cluster pool into the code? I tried the sample code used in https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-pool . But  `require('mysql').Client` returning undefined. So I cant test it. I installed 'npm install mysql '

I am using:

ejs 1.0.0,
        express 3.5.1,
        express-myconnection 1.0.4,
        jade,
        mysql 2.2.0,
        cluster-pool "https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-pool "

Is there any valuable tutorial site available for studying nodejs?

Comment: `cluster-pool` is just a connections pool that could hold connections to different hosts in a single pool. It was designed to be used with replica sets. I can't see how it could help you with your task, since [sharding](http://goo.gl/eUzWNC) is not the same thing as [replication](http://goo.gl/nFKxAh). By the way, sharding is usually implemented on DB level, though it's possible to implement it on application level.

Comment: ok fine. So please tell me how could I use replication through cluster-pool When I used require('mysql').Client it returning undefined.

Comment: Looks like `cluster-pool` was abbandoned back in 2013. Probably, it was designed for an old `mysql` module and not compatible with the latest one. Though, latest `mysql` module have [it's own `PoolCluster` implementation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#poolcluster). So, I don't think you actually need `cluster-pool` after all.

Comment: Thanks @leonid it had worked. Can you make it as an answer, so I can upvote it.